# Jquery - Change an class with "=" in it

Tags: jquery

I have an website with URL`s like example.com/index.php?p=home
An this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pathname = jQuery.url.attr("query");
    $('.tab_container').append(' .'+ pathname +' ');

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $(' .'+ pathname +' ').show();

    //On Click Event
    $("#sidebar-menu a").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar-menu a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

And and html width divs that contain the pages class like

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content p=home">
```

Can I have an script that will remove the = sign from the path name variable and from the classes of div`s?

Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is that an `=` sign is not a valid CSS classname character. For more on this issue, [see this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Comment: This is why I need a script that will remove the = sign! And I did that thanks to the guys below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathname = pathname.replace(/=/g,'');`
`classes = document.getElementById('tab1').className;`
`$('#tab1').removeClass().addClass(classes.replace(/=/g,'');`

Since my answer was accepted I better make it more like Phrogz's answer, which was voted up. The attr set function is nice:

```
$('div[class*="'+pathname+'"]').attr('class',function(i,className){  
  return className.replace(/=/g,'');  
});
pathname = pathname.replace(/=/g,'');
```

Comment: Thank you! I used only the first line witch worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are producing invalid HTML, it is not guaranteed how the browser will expose the classes of elements to the browser. You could try:

```
$('div[class*="'+pathname+'"]').attr('class',function(i,className){
  return className.replace(/=/g,'');
});
```

This uses the ["Attribute Contains" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to find a div with this string in it, and the [`attr` setter method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to change the value.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you! I combined your answer with the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Since, I see that the URL is a PHP page,
will not it be easier to use PHP to store the variable (`$_GET['p']`) and then run a `str_replace` on it (or `strtr`), and pass this variable to jQuery?

(Its just a suggestion, since the page is a PHP page. I am sorry, if this doesnt apply to you)

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, I don`t know PHP and it`s not made by me. I need something that will not need to change the PHP code.